# How to disable WELD on WildFly

Tags: java, jboss, cdi, weld, wildfly

How to fully disable WELD on WildFly. I don't need it, because I use another DI framework.

> Exception 0 :
>   javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unable to resolve a bean for 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations' with qualifiers [@javax.enterprise.inject.Any(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Default()].
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.cdi.MongoRepositoryExtension.createRepositoryBean(MongoRepositoryExtension.java:104)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.cdi.MongoRepositoryExtension.afterBeanDiscovery(MongoRepositoryExtension.java:79)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:93)
>       at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:266)
>       at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:125)
>       at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:253)
>       at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:232)
>       at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:169)

I tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:weld="http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd
                       http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans_1_1.xsd
http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans ">

<weld:scan>
    <weld:exclude name="com.google.**"/>
    <weld:exclude name="org.springframework.data.mongodb.**"/>
</weld:scan>
```

But it did not resolve my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try deleting or commenting out the `org.jboss.as.weld` extension in the extensions list on the beginning of `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml`. You may also want to delete `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:1.0"/>` from `<profile>`. This should cause disabling Weld for all applications deployed on the server.

Comment: You can also use the CLI command to remove the subsystem. `$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c "/subsystem=weld:remove"`.

Answer (score 18):

There's the standard way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                       http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
   version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="none">
</beans>
```

Comment: This is the more appropriate answer, and is not app server specific.  I fear many people will face this issue in coming weeks as more app servers launch w/ EE 7 compliance.

Comment: Yes, even I agree this is a better solution:)

Comment: Note that the above XML should be saved as `WEB-INF/beans.xml` for war files, or as `META-INF/beans.xml` for jar files.

Comment: This disables bean scanning, yes, but the OPs question was how to *disable weld*... So this does not fully answer the question I think. However, maybe the OP just asks the wrong question  :)

Answer (score 16):

### Option 1: jboss-all.xml in the war

This is Weld-specific, but it disables Weld's automatic bean scanning for an entire deployment (eg a war file and all the jars inside it).  This is handy when you can't easily add `beans.xml` to a third-party jar, such as jboss-seam-resteasy.jar.

Save as `WEB-INF/jboss-all.xml` for wars, `META-INF/jboss-all.xml` otherwise:

```
<jboss xmlns="urn:jboss:1.0">
    <weld xmlns="urn:jboss:weld:1.0" require-bean-descriptor="true"/>
</jboss>
```

See [Per-deployment configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/CDI+Reference).

### Option 2: standalone.xml in WildFly

Another option, which doesn't require changing the application itself, is to [configure the weld subsystem not to treat random jars as CDI libraries](http://weld.cdi-spec.org/documentation/#4).  Just edit the configuration for weld in WildFly's `standalone.xml` to look like this:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:2.0" require-bean-descriptor="true"/>
```

Comment: Option 1 is the way to go :)
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/CDI+Reference

Comment: Just adding this detail to the previous (correct) answer: for ear packages the jboss-all.xml file must be located in the ear META-INF folder.