# Jboss seam 2.2.2 on Wildfly 8.0 Final

Tags: seam, wildfly

I hve a working seam application (WAR) based on seam 2.2.2 and i would like to get it running on Wildfly.
We I try to deploy it I get a stande Exception

```
2014-06-19 12:56:35,669 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."TestApp.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."TestApp.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000071: Managed bean class org.jboss.seam.resteasy.ResourceHome must be @Dependent
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.checkType(ManagedBean.java:198)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractBean.initializeAfterBeanDiscovery(AbstractBean.java:103)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.initializeAfterBeanDiscovery(ManagedBean.java:113)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$AfterBeanDiscoveryInitializerFactory.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:129)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$AfterBeanDiscoveryInitializerFactory.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:120)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    ... 3 more
```

could you please give me any hint, what I forgot to configure? I read posts that seam 2.2.2 works on wildfly, so I think it should be possible to solve this tricky problem

Thanking you very much in advance for helping me

Shane

Comment: Seam 2.3 works 2.2.2 i doubt it, in any case disable cdi being activated http://weld.cdi-spec.org/documentation/#4

Comment: You can solve this by disabling Weld:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/21756859